# optimization problem, minimize from a matrix with constraints

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints, minimum

I'm trying to find a minimum for a function which takes a 5x4 matrix shown below.

```
def objective(w):
    ...
    return value

# Random Initial Input Matrix where rows sum up to 1.0
w = array(
      [[0.33333333, 0.        , 0.2       , 0.46666667],
       [0.07142857, 0.42857143, 0.5       , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.42857143, 0.        , 0.57142857],
       [0.31034483, 0.27586207, 0.27586207, 0.13793103],
       [0.27272727, 0.22727273, 0.22727273, 0.27272727]])
```

The only constraint is to keep each row sum up to 1.0.

I've tried

1) `scipy.optimize.fmin(objective, w)` - which gives me back a converging result, but is incorrect because I'm not sure how to apply the constraint.

2) `scipy.optimize.minimize(objective, w)` - which isn't changing the initial matrix.

Any suggestions of what I can look at?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `scipy.optimize.minimize` has a few nonlinear solvers that allow constraints (cobyla, slsqp, trust-constr). Of course, not knowing anything about the objective makes it difficult to say much more. It looks likes you may have a nonlinear objective and linear constraints. They tend to be easier to solve than nonlinearly constrained problems (and there are even specialized algorithms for this case outside `scipy` ).

Comment: Without knowing the definition of `objective` and what you are actually trying to do it is hard to help. But you can also normalize `w` inside your function (bit ugly though): `a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])` then `a / np.sum(a, axis=1, keepdims=True)` will normalize each row sum to `1`.